# Toggling a class in react component effects all returned list

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick, toggle

I am trying to toggle a class attribute in my list element after a click event which is being returned by the map method. The problem I am facing is the toggled "active" class is getting reflected for the inactive li element as well after clicking. Below is my code please help thanks in advance.

```
import '../../Utility/css/sidebar.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Sidebar(){
  const [isActive , setActive] = useState(false);

  const toggleClass =()=>{
    setActive(!isActive);
  }

  const sideMenuJson =[
    {
    name :'Home',
    pass:'inbox',
    pass2:'fa fa-home',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-success'},
  {
    name :'Free Data',
    pass:'',
    pass2:'"fa fa-shopping-cart',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-danger'
  },
  {
    name :'Paid Data',
    pass:'snooz',
    pass2:'fa fa-line-chart',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-primary'
  },
  {
    name :'Order',
    pass:'done',
    pass2:'fa fa-area-chart',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-warning'
  },
  {
    name :'Transaction',
    pass:'',
    pass2:'fa fa-wrench',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-violet'
  },
  {
    name :'Profile',
    pass:'',
    pass2:'fa fa-wrench',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-violet'
  }
]; 
    return (
      <nav className="rad-sidebar primary-bg-color">
        <ul className="list-unstyled">
        { 
        sideMenuJson.map(item =>
          <li className={isActive ? "active": null} 
           onClick={toggleClass} >
            <a href="/" className={item.pass}>
              <i className={item.pass2}>
                  <span className={item.spanclass}></span>
              </i>
              <span className="rad-sidebar-item">{item.name}</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          )
         }
        </ul>
      </nav>
    )
}
```

Comment: Move what is happening in the map funciton (JSX)  into it's own component then set and create a state there.
As it is right now, you have only one isActive state for all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `active` class on the index base, as you can see in the code below, I hope this is helpful.

```
import '../../Utility/css/sidebar.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Sidebar(){
  const [isActive , setActive] = useState(false);

  const toggleClass =(i)=>{
    setActive(i);
  }

  const sideMenuJson =[
    {
    name :'Home',
    pass:'inbox',
    pass2:'fa fa-home',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-success'},
  {
    name :'Free Data',
    pass:'',
    pass2:'"fa fa-shopping-cart',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-danger'
  },
  {
    name :'Paid Data',
    pass:'snooz',
    pass2:'fa fa-line-chart',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-primary'
  },
  {
    name :'Order',
    pass:'done',
    pass2:'fa fa-area-chart',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-warning'
  },
  {
    name :'Transaction',
    pass:'',
    pass2:'fa fa-wrench',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-violet'
  },
  {
    name :'Profile',
    pass:'',
    pass2:'fa fa-wrench',
    spanclass:'icon-bg rad-bg-violet'
  }
]; 
    return (
      <nav className="rad-sidebar primary-bg-color">
        <ul className="list-unstyled">
        { 
        sideMenuJson.map((item, index) =>
          <li className={isActive === index ? "active": null} 
           onClick={() => toggleClass(index)} >
            <a href="/" className={item.pass}>
              <i className={item.pass2}>
                  <span className={item.spanclass}></span>
              </i>
              <span className="rad-sidebar-item">{item.name}</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          )
         }
        </ul>
      </nav>
    )
}
```